# How to join 3 tables for these situation

Tags: mysql, join

I want to join 3 tables

```
Table employer:
+-------------+-------------+---------+
| employer_id | position_id | shop_id |
+-------------+-------------+---------+
|     1       |      2      |    2    |
|     2       |      2      |    2    |
|     3       |      2      |    2    |
|     4       |      1      |    1    |
|     5       |      1      |    2    |
+-------------+-------------+---------+

Table position:
+-------------+-----------------+
| position_id |  position_name  |
+-------------+-----------------+
|     1       |  Receptionist   |
|     2       |  Secretary      |
+-------------+-----------------+

Table shop:
+---------+-----------+
| shop_id | shop_name |
+---------+-----------+
|    1    | Shop ABC  |
|    2    | Shop DEF  |
+---------+-----------+
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT S.*, P.*, E.*, COUNT(E.employer_id) AS NumberOfJobs FROM ((shop AS S INNER JOIN employer AS E ON S.shop_id=E.shop_id) INNER JOIN position AS P ON P.position_id=E.position_id) GROUP BY S.shop_id;
```

The result i get:

```
Shop ABC  
   Receptionist   Job Available : 1  

Shop DEF  
   Secretary      Job Available : 4
```

But what i want is:

```
Shop ABC  
   Receptionist   Job Available : 1  

Shop DEF  
   Receptionist   Job Available : 1    
   Secretary      Job Available : 3
```

What is the correct query to get the result i want? Appreciate if someone could help me to solve this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by shop and position, not just shop:

```
SELECT  S._Id , S.Shop_Name
        P.Position_Name ,
        COUNT(E.employer_id) AS NumberOfJobs
FROM    shop AS S
INNER JOIN employer AS E ON S.shop_id = E.shop_id
INNER JOIN position AS P ON P.position_id = E.position_id

GROUP BY S.shop_id, S.Shop_Name, P.Position_Name
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your query and "Shop DEF" will display twice. How to display only one "Shop DEF"?

Comment: you're mixing up the UI in the database query. This query will get you all the information you need to present to the user, your user interface should display it in the format you want